# Does the JavaScript exec() Method Return an Array or Array-Like Object?

Tags: javascript, regex

My question does not involve a problem, but rather what might be considered somewhat arcane knowledge by some.

I am studying the JavaScript flavor of regular expressions right now with an online course. I put together the code in the listing below to use and output to a Node.js terminal window the results returned by exec. Here is the code:

```js
const testString = 'The phone rang 3 times. No answer. I called a 10 digit' +
                   ' phone number. After 12 calls, I gave up.';

const regex = /\d+/;  // Returns the first match of 1 or more digits.

result = regex.exec(testString);

console.log(testString);
```

As expected, I got the result in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, the expected result is returned. So I achieved the result I was looking for.

My question is this. It seems that the `exec()` method returns an array that contains properties expressed in key-value pairs, yet these key-value pairs are not enclosed in curly braces—e.g.
`{ index: 15 }`.

It would seem this should cause an error message, but it doesn't. So I am wondering if what is returned is an array-like object rather than an array.

Any insights here are greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Robert Hieger

Comment: MDN Docs: "The exec() method executes a search for a match in a specified string and returns a result array, or null."
Source:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: The output of `console.log()` doesn't have the be valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @PoulBak Doesn't really make a difference, all of them return arrays with extra properties

Answer (score 0):

The console API outputs values in their own way. There is no rule that this output should follow some (JavaScript) syntax, and may include all kinds of formatting, coloring, expand-buttons, placeholders, non-enumerable properties, private fields, ECMAScript slots, ...etc.

The result of `exec` is an instance of `Array`, augmented with some extra properties. For this kind of object there doesn't exist a JSON expression that reflects it correctly. JSON can represent Arrays, but then without any extra properties, or plain objects, but then they are not recognised as arrays.

You can verify yourself that it is an `instanceof Array`, and also print it as a plain object JSON. The following code does that. I made the example a bit less trivial, also including a named capture group:

```js
const result = /(?<first>\d)\d*/.exec('Suzy is 24 years old');

console.log(result instanceof Array); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(result)); // true

// Create a non-Array object with same enumerable properties, 
// and print it as JSON:
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, result)));
```

Some remarks:

- With `JSON.stringify(result)` you would only get the array output without the additional properties.
- If you would want to synthesise such an object in a single expression, it could look something like this:

  ```
  const result = Object.assign([24, 2], {     
    "index":8,
    "input":"Suzy is 24 years old",
    "groups":{"first":"2"}
  });
  ```